# productivity and self improvement questions

Tags: discussion, support, questions, tags

You can ask productivity and self improvement questions related to programming or computers on software engineering stack exchange .

See for example this question ,
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141860/should-i-be-concerned-that-i-cant-program-very-fast-without-google

Why can we not have such tags on physics stack exchange?

I am a very slow and inefficient learner ,thats why even if I have great love for  physics ,I get  average or below average grades.I would also like to improve my problem solving skills .

May be there are other people like me having the same problems ,they can get help on physics SE.

So why not such tags?

Comment: Because those questions would be off topic as *opinion-based*?

Comment: Some (but not all) such questions are considered on-topic at [academia.se].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my eyes, physics.SE is about the *science* of physics, not about the *practice* of physics. As such, questions about study advice, career advice, personal productivity when studying physics, etc. are off-topic here. We don't have tags for the things you ask about because having tags for questions which will almost surely be off-topic is not useful.

It should be this way because all of these questions are inherently opinion-based - what works for me need not work for you, and every personal situation has more deciding factors than one can reasonably communicate through a single SE question. I come here in order to ask and answer *questions about physics*, and allowing questions about things not related to the science of physics as such would decrease the signal-to-noise ratio considerably from my viewpoint.